# Shuffling list, but keeping some elements frozen

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've such a problem:

There is a list of elements of class `CAnswer` (no need to describe the class), and I need to shuffle it, but with one constraint - some elements of the list have `CAnswer.freeze` set to `True`, and those elements must not be shuffled, but remain on their original positions. So, let's say, for a given list:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

Where all elements are instances of `CAnswer`, but `c.freeze == True`, and for others `freeze == False`, the possible outcome could be:

```
[e, a, c, f, b, d]
```

So element with index 2 is still on its position.

What is the best algorithm to achieve it?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I've tried two approaches - first using just random.shuffle() and then restoring certain elements to it's original positions. Another one consisted on using random.choice for elements to be randomized, or selecting certain elements for "frozen" elements. However both of theese approaches seem to be a little bit unelegant, and definitely not pythonic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another solution:

```
# memorize position of fixed elements
fixed = [(pos, item) for (pos,item) in enumerate(items) if item.freeze]
# shuffle list
random.shuffle(items)
# swap fixed elements back to their original position
for pos, item in fixed:
    index = items.index(item)
    items[pos], items[index] = items[index], items[pos]
```

Comment: This is what i did, but in less pythonic way - without list comprehension and whithout itearating simultanously over two elements, so thanks!

Comment: Just implemented this in my script and works perfectly, being very pythonic and elegant at the same time. Thanks a lot once again! Members of StackOverflow rule the world ;)

Comment: @Pawel: this solution might break if there are duplicates in the list. Also (less important) items.index() can scan the whole list for a single value. It makes the algorithm quadratic in time.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian You are right, thanks for pointing this out! However, for the problem at hand (shuffling answers to quiz questions) neither should pose a problem.

Comment: They're not excatly answers to Quiz question, but something similar - answers in a survey system. There are no duplicates to be expected in the list at its lenght will rarely be over 10 and almost never over 30 items, so I find this way fitting my needs perfectly - it's clear, simple, and, what's probably most important to me - easy to understand. I'm a python newbie (and not a programmer or even IT guy) so I needed some code I will understand and learn something.

Comment: Simple and maybe good enough, but please note the if it is **important to shuffle just the items that are not frozen** this solution seems brittle.  It will randomize a bigger set than intended.  This will become more and more noticable as the number of fixed elements become larger in proportion to the total number of elements in the list.

Answer (score 12):

One solution:

```
def fixed_shuffle(lst):
    unfrozen_indices, unfrozen_subset = zip(*[(i, e) for i, e in enumerate(lst)
                                            if not e.freeze])
    unfrozen_indices = list(unfrozen_indices)
    random.shuffle(unfrozen_indices)
    for i, e in zip(unfrozen_indices, unfrozen_subset):
        lst[i] = e
```

NOTE: If `lst` is a [numpy array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) instead of a regular list, this can be a bit simpler:

```
def fixed_shuffle_numpy(lst):
    unfrozen_indices = [i for i, e in enumerate(lst) if not e.freeze]
    unfrozen_set = lst[unfrozen_indices]
    random.shuffle(unfrozen_set)
    lst[unfrozen_indices] = unfrozen_set
```

An example of its usage:

```
class CAnswer:
    def __init__(self, x, freeze=False):
        self.x = x
        self.freeze = freeze

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return self.x.__cmp__(other.x)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<CAnswer: %s>" % self.x


lst = [CAnswer(3), CAnswer(2), CAnswer(0, True), CAnswer(1), CAnswer(5),
       CAnswer(9, True), CAnswer(4)]

fixed_shuffle(lst)
```

Comment: Seems nice, and should work, but as a noob i need a few secs to understand that. Thank's a lot!

Comment: Nice code. Shuffles the unfrozen indices and nothing else.

Answer (score 10):

In linear time, constant space using [`random.shuffle() source`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/random.py#l276):

```
from random import random

def shuffle_with_freeze(x):
    for i in reversed(xrange(1, len(x))):
        if x[i].freeze: continue # fixed
        # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
        j = int(random() * (i+1))
        if x[j].freeze: continue #NOTE: it might make it less random
        x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i] # swap
```

Answer (score 1):

Overengineered solution: create a wrapper class that contains indexes of the unfreezed elements and emulates a list, and make sure the setter writes to the original list:

```
class IndexedFilterList:
    def __init__(self, originalList, filterFunc):
        self.originalList = originalList
        self.indexes = [i for i, x in enumerate(originalList) if filterFunc(x)]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.indexes)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.originalList[self.indexes[i]]

    def __setitem__(self, i, value):
        self.originalList[self.indexes[i]] = value
```

And call:

```
random.shuffle(IndexedFilterList(mylist, lambda c: not c.freeze))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that a list has fast remove and insert:

- enumerate fixed elements and copy them and their index
- delete fixed elements from list
- shuffle remaining sub-set
- put fixed elements back in

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25233037/3449962 for a more general solution.

This will use in-place operations with memory overhead that depends on the number of fixed elements in the list.  Linear in time. A possible implementation of `shuffle_subset`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Shuffle elements in a list, except for a sub-set of the elments.

The sub-set are those elements that should retain their position in
the list.  Some example usage:

>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> class CAnswer(namedtuple("CAnswer","x fixed")):
...             def __bool__(self):
...                     return self.fixed is True
...             __nonzero__ = __bool__  # For Python 2. Called by bool in Py2.
...             def __repr__(self):
...                     return "<CA: {}>".format(self.x)
...
>>> val = [3, 2, 0, 1, 5, 9, 4]
>>> fix = [2, 5]
>>> lst = [ CAnswer(v, i in fix) for i, v in enumerate(val)]

>>> print("Start   ", 0, ": ", lst)
Start    0 :  [<CA: 3>, <CA: 2>, <CA: 0>, <CA: 1>, <CA: 5>, <CA: 9>, <CA: 4>]

Using a predicate to filter.

>>> for i in range(4):  # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
...     shuffle_subset(lst, lambda x : x.fixed)
...     print([lst[i] for i in fix], end=" ")
...
[<CA: 0>, <CA: 9>] [<CA: 0>, <CA: 9>] [<CA: 0>, <CA: 9>] [<CA: 0>, <CA: 9>]

>>> for i in range(4):                # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
...     shuffle_subset(lst)           # predicate = bool()
...     print([lst[i] for i in fix], end=" ")
...
[<CA: 0>, <CA: 9>] [<CA: 0>, <CA: 9>] [<CA: 0>, <CA: 9>] [<CA: 0>, <CA: 9>]

"""
from __future__ import print_function
import random


def shuffle_subset(lst, predicate=None):
    """All elements in lst, except a sub-set, are shuffled.

    The predicate defines the sub-set of elements in lst that should
    not be shuffled:

      + The predicate is a callable that returns True for fixed
      elements, predicate(element) --> True or False.

      + If the predicate is None extract those elements where
      bool(element) == True.

    """
    predicate = bool if predicate is None else predicate
    fixed_subset = [(i, e) for i, e in enumerate(lst) if predicate(e)]

    fixed_subset.reverse()      # Delete fixed elements from high index to low.
    for i, _ in fixed_subset:
        del lst[i]

    random.shuffle(lst)

    fixed_subset.reverse()      # Insert fixed elements from low index to high.
    for i, e in fixed_subset:
        lst.insert(i, e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: "Use the fact that a list has fast remove and insert:" it does not, deleting is linear time and insertion is linear time. Only append is constant time.