# shuffling all elements between given two elements

Tags: python, list, random

I know how to shuffle a list of elements. But hos should I do if I want to shuffle all the elements between two specific elements.

```
import random
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
random.shuffle(x)
print(x)
```

I tried following way, but it produce "None".

```
import random
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
random.shuffle(x[2:5]) # need an output like this e.g: [1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(x)
```

But it didnt work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If it's Python-3 then `print x` would be a syntax error!?!

Comment: You are using python 2 code and tagged python 3.

Comment: a small edit should fix that.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You are not sure. What if the OP is using python 2 but accidentally tagged python-3? I have rolledback.

Comment: @BlackThunder bad move, as `print(x)` works very well in python 2. Try it. re-added parentheses, code is version agnostic. Time to get rid of python 2 and `print` statement.

Comment: it's also marked as duplicate, but the answers in the duplicate look soooo complicated. Not one is as simple as the answers below (except that one which is very similar to mine, admitted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9557226/6451573)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/8321664

Comment: @BlackThunder TL;DR adding parentheses to print when there's only one argument does _the same_ in python 2 or python 3. So I don't know what's the issue (I didn't rollback your tags btw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shuffle` works in-place, so you need to take a slice of your list, shuffle it, and then slice-reassign to the original list.

```
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> 
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Create a shuffled list `shuffled`.

```
>>> shuffle_range = slice(2, 5)
>>> shuffled = x[shuffle_range]
>>> shuffle(shuffled)
```

Reassign the `shuffled` part to a slice of the original list:

```
>>> x[shuffle_range] = shuffled
>>> 
>>> x
[1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I created the `slice(2, 5)` object in order to not repeat myself typing the indices.

`x` is mutated in-place in this approach, just like you would expect from an ordinary shuffle-operation.

Comment: this is probably the most performant (also cryptic :)) answer. `slice` is underused sometimes.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre less cryptic now? :)

Comment: it was a joke. I just forgot to use `slice`, and it's a lesser known feature. It could just lose others :) good answer.

Answer (score 3):

`shuffle` works in place. So what happens is that your list slice `x[2:5]` is shuffled, then discarded as it has no reference left.

You'd have to do:

```
part = x[2:5]
random.shuffle(part)
x = x[:2] + part + x[5:]
```

This naïve approach which recreates a copy of `x`. If `x` is huge and you just shuffle a small part of it, the memory overhead is too much. Commenters suggested to replace the last line by a better slice assignment:

```
x[2:5] = part
```

Comment: Or `x[2:5] = part` to update the shuffled slice without creating a copy of the whole list.

Comment: yes, timgeb answer has a better way of doing it.

Comment: Actually, I like your version better (with @Aran-Fey's suggestion). Easier to read, and the repetition doesn't bother me :)

Comment: thanks. Repetitiion can be avoided by `slice`, but also by `a=2;b=5` then use `a:b`, so not a big issue...