# Shuffling part of a list in-place

Tags: python, random, shuffle, in-place

I have a `list` and I want to shuffle a portion of it **in-place**.

I am aware of `random.shuffle()` and that it works in-place, but if I slice the list, it shuffles the sliced copy of the original input, leaving the original `list` untouched:

```
import random

l = list(range(20))
print(l)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]

random.shuffle(l[:10])  # I wish it was shuffling the first half
print(l)  # but does nothing to `l`
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

What options do I have?

---

**EDIT**: This is not truly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557182/python-shuffle-only-some-elements-of-a-list), since there was no requirement for it to be **in-place**. Eventually, it seems that it would be possible to shuffle in-place a portion of a list only *manually* (which is exactly what I was trying to avoid), as suggested by [one of the answers posted there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31416673).

Comment: See if this link helps - [Python - shuffle only some elements of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557182/python-shuffle-only-some-elements-of-a-list)

Comment: After looking at [the Source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/random.py) I ended up with ... [this exact answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31416673): a patched `shuffle` where you have to provide start and end as arguments.

Comment: @usr2564301 Thanks! While OP in the question was after something else, obviously that answer addresses (a bit disappointgly, though) my issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could use [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to fundamentally re-implement [`random.shuffle()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/random.py) to accept a `first` and `last` index as arguments, e.g.:

```
import random


def valid_index(i, n):
    assert(-n <= i < n)
    return i % n


def shuffle(seq, first=0, last=-1, rand_int_gen=None):
    n = len(seq)
    first = valid_index(first, n)
    last = valid_index(last, n)
    # use Fisher-Yates shuffle (Durstenfeld method)
    if callable(rand_int_gen):
        for i in range(first, last):
            j = rand_int_gen(i, last)
            seq[i], seq[j] = seq[j], seq[i]
    else:
        getrandbits = random.getrandbits
        for i in range(first, last + 1):
            size = last - i + 1
            j = getrandbits(size.bit_length()) % size + i
            seq[i], seq[j] = seq[j], seq[i]
    return seq
```

to be used like:

```
l = list(range(20))
print(l)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]

random.seed(0)  # just to show reproducible results
shuffle(l, 0, 9)
print(l)
# [6, 7, 2, 5, 8, 4, 9, 3, 0, 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Time-wise this is actually even a few percent faster than `random.shuffle()` for shuffling the whole sequence.

This is faster essentially because it gets the random values directly from `random.getrandbits()` which is the closest method exposed by `random` for random integer generation, the others, e.g. `randint()` and `randrange()` eventually reducing to this.
These last two eventually use internally `_getrandbelow()` which could be calling `getrandbits()` more often the necessary.

```
for k in range(1, 7): 
    n = 10 ** k 
    print(n) 
    %timeit l = list(range(n)); random.shuffle(l) 
    %timeit l = list(range(n)); shuffle(l) 
    print()
```

```
10
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.16 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.85 µs per loop

100
10000 loops, best of 3: 54.3 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 28 µs per loop

1000
1000 loops, best of 3: 585 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 341 µs per loop

10000
100 loops, best of 3: 6.01 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.56 ms per loop

100000
10 loops, best of 3: 71.7 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 44.1 ms per loop

1000000
1 loop, best of 3: 815 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 582 ms per loop
```

This approach was also suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31416673), as pointed out by @usr2564301.
Unfortunately, I think there is no better approach for doing this operation in-place.

Answer (score 3):

Not really in-place but with the desired result:

```
import random

l = list(range(20))

lpart = l[:10]
random.shuffle(lpart)

l[:10] = lpart

print(l)
```

Answer (score 2):

Modifying the list n-place won't work on just a slice of the list. You could use `random.sample` instead to take random samples without replacement, and slice assign back:

```
k = 10
l[:k] = random.sample(l[:k], k=k)
```

---

```
print(l)
# [1, 7, 6, 0, 2, 3, 4, 9, 8, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```