# How to shuffle only 'n' random elements in python list?

Tags: python, list, shuffle

python's `random.shuffle` shuffle all or random no of elements? In present scenario only want to shuffle fixed number of elements as shown below

```
inp_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

# shuffle any 2 elements
op_list_1 = [1,2,3,4,9,6,7,8,5]

# shuffle any 4 element
op_list_4 = [8,2,5,4,3,6,7,1,9]
```

Comment: What is that you have tried or found that is not working expect for `random.shuffle` ?

Comment: Does this help: [Python - shuffle only some elements of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557182/python-shuffle-only-some-elements-of-a-list)?

Comment: What you mean by any 2 or any 4?

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion. See comments in code for further explanation.  (The test list here has larger numbers than the one in the question, to avoid any confusion between the indices and the values.)

```
import random

inp_list = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]

num = 3  # how many elements to shuffle

# obtain list of indices that will be shuffled
indices = random.sample(range(len(inp_list)), num)

# keep trying to build up a dictionary of mappings
# between old and new position, until it is successful
#
# Define "succcess" as meaning that no item is back in 
# its original position
#
shuffled_indices = indices.copy()
success = False
while not success:
    random.shuffle(shuffled_indices)
    mapping = { a:b for a, b in zip(indices, shuffled_indices) }
    for a, b in mapping.items():
        if a == b:
            success = False
            break
    else:
        success = True

# Now apply the mappings

out_list = inp_list.copy()
for a, b in mapping.items():
    out_list[a] = inp_list[b]

print(out_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with. Sample indices to be shuffled, shuffle them and replace the old list with the new values.

```
def shuffle(input_list, count=2):
    '''Shuffles any n number of values in a list'''
    indices_to_shuffle = random.sample(range(len(input_list)), k=count)
    to_shuffle = [input_list[i] for i in indices_to_shuffle]
    random.shuffle(to_shuffle)
    for index, value in enumerate(to_shuffle):
        old_index = indices_to_shuffle[index]
        input_list[old_index] = value
    return input_list
```

```
>>> shuffle([11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99])
[11, 88, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 22, 99]
```

Comment: It seems that we have broadly similar approaches for getting the initial list of indices, but then we diverge because I assumed that an attempted shuffle in which some elements randomly happen to end up in their original positions would not count -- i.e. we want "count" elements to definitely change position. The only way I could think of avoiding this was just trying repeatedly until it is successful -- which could be quite slow if it is shuffling a large number of elements (likely to fail so many retries needed). I would be interested if you can think of a more efficient way to do that.

Answer (score -1):

shuffle all, then merge partially the original one with a shuffled (perhaps using a bitmap with n 1s and rest 0s)

Comment: Why don't you show usage with some code..

Comment: @sushanth It wouldn't work anyway. Simple example: suppose list has 3 elements and we want to shuffle 2 of them. Shuffle all: `a,b,c -> b,c,a`. Then applying bitmap `1,1,0` to do partial merge gives `b,c,c`, which is not a shuffled version of the initial list.

Comment: @alaniwi, slice the original array with a bitmap, shuffle, insert back again on same indices